# Execute code outside the update transaction

Tags: seam

I need to execute two things on update():

- commit entity to the database
- send the entity through JMS

Because the object is quite large the send through JMS has to be outside the database transaction. Problem is that Seam adds the transaction based on JSF phases and so the database transaction is already active as soon as my own overridden update() is called.

Adding a call-back to the update like afterUpdate() would be nice but this does not seem to be possible.

Question:
How can I commit the entity and after that execute code outside the transaction?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you could use @PostPersist to trigger the JMS action?

Comment: I think that would still be within the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the transaction used is a Spring transaction. That allows for something like:

```
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case STATUS_COMMITTED:
                    LOGGER.debug("update::afterCompletion");
                    afterCompletionCallback();
                    break;
                case STATUS_ROLLED_BACK:
                    break;
                case STATUS_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

The transaction is then still available but the database is not locked anymore and any timeouts don't effect the Seam transaction.